Creating a dashboard for end users that displays data from azure SQL tables
Is there any functionality available within Azure Portal to create a dashboard for end users that displays data from Azure SQL queries?
I have done this in on premise using DotNet and React so need to know if there is any simpler way in Azure

Yes, you can use Power BI with direct query. More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/tutorial-connect-power-bi-desktop
